# Does retagging turn up in a user's activity list?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, recent-activity

Is an edit of tags supposed to turn up in a user's activity list?

If not, what is the reason?

An example is [Sridhar Ratnakumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55246?tab=activity#sort-top)'s retagging of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/python-how-to-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows).

**Update 1**: there might be a problem with that particular question. It is not a general problem; see Kip's answer.

**Update 2**: the accepted answer was changed after the retagging. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: It should show 'revised'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** You're right, the retag on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/python-how-to-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows) does not show up, the retag I circled on the screenshot below is a different retag. As far as I know this *should* be showing up, so I think this is a bug. (Especially since another question's retag *does* show up.)

---

<del>Your question makes it sound like the retag doesn't show up, and you want to know if this is a bug or if there is a reason.</del>

But it does show up:

http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/7728/retag.png

Comment: That's a mighty neatly-done hand-drawn circle, there.

Comment: No, that is a different question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129 is "Python: how to install SciPy on 64 bit Windows?"

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: sorry, i realized that after i posted this. my answer has been updated.

Comment: But you are correct that for http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1968539 the retagging turns up in the activity list. Perhaps it is a problem with one particular question?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way when we've re-written the activity page <s>one</s> <s>two</s> three times, this was fixed.  See, [it's in his history now](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55246/sridhar-ratnakumar?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=14)!